# Python: is there a way to a Pandas Series object directly without using a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, data-structures, series

My goal is to create a new Pandas Series object based on a set of user-defined inputs. I'm currently going about this task with the following code:

```
new_list = []
for _ in range(int(input("Enter number of entries: "))):
    new_list.append(input("Enter an element for the list: "))

new_series = pd.Series(new_list)
print(new_series)
```

Works fine. However, I'm wondering if there's a way to create the `new_series` Series object without appending and passing in `new_list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit - I think I prefer the other answer, but have left here as an example of `.append`

You could append directly to a series object:

```py
s = pd.Series()
for _ in range(int(input("Enter number of entries: "))):
    s.append(pd.Series(input("Enter an element for the list: ")))
print(s)
```

eg:

```py
In [14]: s = pd.Series()

In [15]: for _ in range(int(input('entries : '))):
    ...:     s = s.append(pd.Series(input('el : ')))
    ...:
entries : 5
el : 3
el : 2
el : 1
el : 6
el : 7

In [16]: s
Out[16]:
0    3
0    2
0    1
0    6
0    7
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, like this?

```
new_series = pd.Series(dtype='int')
for i in range(int(input("Enter number of entries: "))):
    new_series.loc[i] = input("Enter an element for the list: ")

print(new_series)
```

Output:

```
Enter number of entries: 3
Enter an element for the list: 1
Enter an element for the list: 2
Enter an element for the list: 3
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: object
```